# Using require in component, Does it create a reference to the "required" controller or makes a copy?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a few components that are contained in a parent component.
All the child components require the parent component controller, 
So I wonder if requiring the controller multiple times will hit the performance since the controller properties are copied each time or it's done by reference, and then I guess that would be just fine?

```
angular.module('app')
    .component('main', {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/main/main.html',
      controller : MainController,
      controllerAs: 'main'
    });


angular.module('app')
  .component('footer', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/footer/footer.html',
    controller: function() {
    },
    require: {
      main: '^main'
    }
  });

angular.module('app')
  .component('header', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/header/header.html',
    controller : function() {
    },
    require    : {
      main: '^main'
    }
  });
  .
  .
  .
```

Cheers,
Idanb11

Comment: it's done by reference;  if they were copied, then the child wouldn't be able to see if the parent was updated.

Comment: Thanks @Claies,

That was my guess.